# looping through array and printing element to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through an `array` and have the images display to screen. This is only displaying my last one but when I console log `crystalImg[i]` I get all the images. I'm not sure what I am doing that it's only displaying the last image.

```
var crystalImg = ["assets/images/blue.png",
"assets/images/pink.png",
"assets/images/purple.png",
"assets/images/red.png"];

for (i = 0; i < crystalImg.length; i++) {
  $("#jewels").html("<img src='" + crystalImg[i] + "'>");
  console.log(crystalImg[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the entire HTML, use the [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function instead.

```js
var crystalImg = ["assets/images/blue.png", "assets/images/pink.png", 
"assets/images/purple.png", "assets/images/red.png"];

for (i = 0; i < crystalImg.length; i++) {
    $("#jewels").append("<img src='" + crystalImg[i] + "'>");
    console.log(crystalImg[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='jewels'>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh blah, you are so right! Brain fart. >.<  Thank you!!